# Perl Issue: contents deleted after grep

Tags: perl

I see the contents of file deleted after perl grep, any reason/fix? I need to take decision if grep is success or not.

```
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "can't read open '$file': $OS_ERROR";
$start_sync=0;
if (grep{/PATTERN/} <$fh>){
    print "word found\n";
    $start_sync=1;
}
else{
    print "word not found\n";
    $start_sync=0;
}
my @lines = <$fh>;  
close $fh or die "can't read close '$file': $OS_ERROR";  
if($start_sync==1) {edit the same file}
```

While the grep itself is working, the contents of the file is blanked/deleted after the grep. Without the grep, this deletion doesnt happen. Wondering what causes the contents to be blanked out.

Comment: if you are going to read all the lines, do it before the grep, and then grep your array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `<$fh>` as the second argument of [grep](http://p3rl.org/grep), it forces list context on the diamond operator, which reads all the lines from the file. When the grep finishes, the filehandle is exhausted and points to [eof](http://p3rl.org/eof).

If you want to read the file again, you need to rewind the filehandle position. Use [seek](http://p3rl.org/seek) for that:

```
seek $fh, 0, 0;
my @lines = <$fh>;
```

or if you love readable code,

```
use Fcntl ':seek';
# ...
seek $fh, 0, SEEK_SET;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `grep` will process all of the elements, so it will look at every line even if you already have your answer. But what if you find it on line 1 of a billion lines? Instead, loop until you find it then stop:

```
while( <$fh> ) {
    next unless /PATTERN/;
    $start_sync = 1;
    last;
    }
```